# How can i define global variables in slim framework

Tags: php, slim

How can i define a global variable such that my current_user method can work were ever i want it to, all i simple need to do is check if there is a current user my example code is below

```
    if (isset($_SESSION['company_id'])) {
       $current_user = Companies::find($_SESSION['company_id']);
     }
    else
   {
    $current_company = null;
   }
```

how can i use the current user method where ever i want without passing it to my `app->render()` method just like in my header.html

```
{% if current_user %}
 hi {{current_user.name}}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: maybe you can put: global $current_user; in your function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was finally able to get it to work with this

```
   $app->hook('slim.before.dispatch', function() use ($app) { 
       $current_company = null;
       if (isset($_SESSION['company_id'])) {
          $current_company = Company::find($_SESSION['company_id']);
       }
       $app->view()->setData('current_company', $current_company);
    });
```

Answer (score 8):

You can inject a value into the app object:

```
$app->foo = 'bar';
```

More on [Slim’s documentation](http://docs.slimframework.com/#DI-Overview).

Answer (score 6):

Injection is not working in the callback function.

To have access to the variable in a callback function you can use `"use() "` function :

```
$mydata =  array (  ... );

$app->get('/api', function(Request $request, Response $response) use($mydata) {  
        echo json_encode($mydata);

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Inject the object it like this:

```
$app->companies = new Companies();
```

You can also inject it as a singleton if you want to make sure its the same one each time:

```
$app->container->singleton('companies', function (){
    return new Companies();
});
```

The call it like this:

```
$app->companies->find($_SESSION['company_id']);
```

UPDATE DOC LINK:
[Slim Dependency Injection](http://docs.slimframework.com/di/overview/)

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer does not work for Slim 3 (as the hooks have been removed).

If you are trying to define a variable for all views and you are using the [PhpRenderer](https://github.com/slimphp/PHP-View), you can follow their example:

```
// via the constructor
$templateVariables = [
    "title" => "Title"
];
$phpView = new PhpRenderer("./path/to/templates", $templateVariables);

// or setter
$phpView->setAttributes($templateVariables);

// or individually
$phpView->addAttribute($key, $value);
```

Answer (score 0):

With twig/view

creating a middleware

```
<?php

namespace ETA\Middleware;

class GlobalVariableMiddleware extends Middleware {

    public function __invoke($request, $response, $next) {

        $current_path = $request->getUri()->getPath();

        $this->container->view->getEnvironment()->addGlobal('current_path', $current_path);

        return $next($request, $response);
    }

}
```