# How to inject global variables in Slim 3 route?

Tags: php, dependency-injection, slim

How do you inject global variable in Slim 3? I found this [How can i define global variables in slim framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23645185/how-can-i-define-global-variables-in-slim-framework), but it references Slim 2.

I have a singleton that configures a Google API:

```
class Google_Config {

    private static $CLIENT_ID = "...";
    private static $CLIENT_SECRET = "...";
    private static $REDIRECT_URI = "...";

    private static $instance = null;

    private $client = null;

    private $scopes = [...];

    private function __construct() {
        $this->client = new Google_Client();
        $this->client->setClientId(self::$CLIENT_ID);
        $this->client->setClientSecret(self::$CLIENT_SECRET);
        $this->client->setRedirectUri(self::$REDIRECT_URI);
        $this->client->setScopes($this->scopes);
    }

    public static function get() {
        if(self::$instance == null) {
            self::$instance = new Google_Config();
        }

        return self::$instance;
    }

}
```

I'm defining the global variable in `index.php` as follows:

```
 $config = Google_Config::get();
```

I tried some of the old methods found in the article I referenced above:

```
$app->config = Google_Config::get(); // index.php

// route.php 
$app->get('/login', function($request, $response, $args) {
    $google = $this->get("AS_Google_Config");
    var_dump($google); // for testing
    return $this->renderer->render($response, 'login.phtml');
});
```

But I get:

```
 Identifier "Google_Config" is not defined.
```

How should I go about using this singleton, but being able to inject it as a dependency so it can be used in *all* routes? Based on what I've seen in the docs (http://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/router.html#container-resolution) it seems like I need to make the constructor public.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm the guy that wrote that section of the documentation.

What you need to do is define it in the container.

```
$container['google_client'] = function ($c) { 
    return Google_Config::get(); 
};
```

Then...

```
$app->get('/login', function($request, $response, $args) {
    $google = $this->get("google_client"); // <--
    var_dump($google); // for testing
    return $this->renderer->render($response, 'login.phtml');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use php env. For example you can use vlucas/phpdotenv. Get it from composer - packagist